# Attribute error in worker messaging thread

Tags: thread-safety, wxpython, messaging

I can't comprehend why the worker function will not accept self.OpenDir object
on the first line.  It will print the directory!  Any explanations are appreciated.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)       
        dispatcher.connect(self.showFrame2, signal="show.mainframe3",
                     sender=dispatcher.Any)       

    def showFrame2(self, message, arg2=None, arg3=None):
        self.new_dbf = message
        self.RegRemove = arg2
        self.OpenDir = arg3 

    def run(self):
        """ worker """
        with open('E:\csv_sorted\Row2.dbf') as infile:
##        with open(self.OpenDir) as infile:  Attribute error!            
            print self.OpenDir            
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            data = StringIO()
            writer = csv.writer(data)
        for line in csv.reader(self.new_dbf.splitlines()):
            row = line
            row_edit = re.sub(self.RegRemove,'', row[1])
            writer.writerow([row[0], row_edit])
            msg = data.getvalue()                
            wx.CallAfter(Publisher().sendMessage, "update", msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining **self.OpenDir** inside of a function that isn't called in **__*init*__**. Thus it does not exist when run is called and you receive an AttributeError.

Comment: so I need to add the run function in the def_init_(self): like def_init_(self, ...  aww I still don't understand

Comment: Technically you would just need to do a **self.start()** to call **run**. But that won't solve the problem because that still doesn't initialize **self.OpenDir**

Comment: I added: self.queue = queue to my thread class and self.queue.get() to the worker.  On the GUI you need to add self.queue.put(whatever) on the button and self.queue = Queue.Queue() in the frame class. [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/lcc9QDI7QDM)  This explains the methodology.   I have another question about this.  Shall I make a new question?

Comment: That would probably be a good idea as StackOverflow frowns on long conversations in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
    class thing:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def something(self):
            self.foo = "bar"


        def tryme(self):
            print self.foo

    a = thing()

    # a.something()

    a.tryme()
```

When you run it, you will get an attribute error, because when `tryme()` is called, `something()` hasn't been run, so there is no such thing as `self.foo`.

If you uncomment `a.something()` it will work.

This is the same problem your code probably has.   You either need to make sure `showFrame2()` gets called before `run()`, or initialize `self.OpenDir` some other way before calling `run()`.

---

(*This is the same answer Mike gave, only more explicit.  You probably should just upvote this one, and accept Mike's, if this turns out to be the right answer for you (or vice versa)*).

Comment: yeah, thats probably what's going on.  I'll re-write this.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please take the time to upvote both answers, and choose one to mark as "correct" by clicking the tick button.   Cheers, GaJ.